# Finding torsion points of given order on elliptic curve

Tags: roots, finite-fields, elliptic-curves, torsion-groups

> Let $y^2=x^3+2x+3$ be an elliptic curve over $\Bbb{F}_7$.  Find all torsion points of order $2$ and $3$ on $E(\Bbb{F}_7)$.

Now I used the recursive formula to obtain that the third division polynomial of $E$ is $f_3(x)=3x^4+12x^2+36x-4$.

Calculating the torsion points of order $2$ is fairly easy -  they correspond to the points for which $y=0$. So taking $y=0$ one can check and see that the points of order two are $\mathcal O,(6,0)$.

But how do we find torsion points of order $3$? Does it have any connection with the third division polynomial? (My professor explained that its roots are the $x$ coordinates of the torsion points of order $3$ but I didn't find this theorem anywhere online).

Every help would be appreciated.

Comment: The result you mention about the 3rd division polynomial and the 3-torsion points is true; you can find it on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_polynomials#Properties), for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is fairly easy to compute the third division polynomial explicitly. Assume that $P \in E(\overline{\Bbb F_p})$ is a $3$-torsion point, that is: $3P=O_E$. Then $2P = -P$. If $E : y^2 = x^3+ax+b$, then a well-known doubling formula gives

$$
x(2P) =  \dfrac{(3x(P)^2 + a)^2}{4 y(P)^2} - 2 x(P) 
= x(-P) = x(P)
$$

This readily implies that $x(P)$ is a root of
$$f_3(x) = (3x^2 + a)^2 - 3x \cdot 4(x^3 + ax + b),$$
which, in our specific case, simplifies into the quartic polynomial $f_3$ that you wrote.

---

We find that the non-trivial 3-torsion points over $\Bbb F_7$ are $(3, \pm 1)$, and indeed 3 is a root of the polynomial $f_3$.

Comment: So basically calculating the roots of the third division polynomial give me the torsion points? And what does $x(2P)$ mean?

Comment: @User121231234 The $x$-coordinate of the point $2P$.

Comment: @User121231234 : $x(2P)$ is the x-coordinate of the point $2P=P+P$. I showed that for any 3-torsion point (x,y), the coordinate x is a root of the third division polynomial. Conversely, if $f_3(x(P)) = 0$ then $x(2P) = x(-P)$ and so $2P = \pm P$, so $3 P = O$ in any case.

Comment: An interesting trick is that the 3-torsion points coincide with the inflection points of the curve (the points where the second derivative of y with respect to x is zero). Try to prove this fact.